# How to programatically check if USB mass storage is enabled on Android 10+ (API 29+)?

Tags: android

I need to programatically check if the USB mass storage is enabled on an Android device, API 29+.
I found [Settings.Global#USB_MASS_STORAGE_ENABLED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global#USB_MASS_STORAGE_ENABLED) that seemed to be exactly what I needed.
Unfortunately, the [Settings.Global.get<ANY_TYPE>()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global#getInt(android.content.ContentResolver,%20java.lang.String)) methods always return "1" with this constant, even though:

- The device is not connected with USB OR it is connected with the "No data transfer" USB mode
- In dev settings, the default USB mode is set to "No data transfer"

I tried disabling Debugging mode and even Developer mode, hoping it would make a difference somehow, with no more success.

I can't see any permission I would need for this check or any additional settings to check to make sure the USB mass storage is disabled.

Am I missing something? Does anybody know how to detect disabled USB mass storage and how to test it? I am not looking for an event, but the current state.

Comment: What do you mean is this context with 'enabled'?

Comment: And what do you mean with 'the USB mass storage' to begin with? What is your scenario?

Comment: I am collecting information about miscellaneous device settings. One of the items I must collect is whether USB mass storage is enabled or not on the device.
It is not a check before any data transfer, it is about knowing the status of this specific setting to inform the user.

Comment: Never saw 'miscellaneous device settings'. Where do you see that? And which device are you talking about? Your Android device? And what would enabled mean? Please tell your scenario and come to the point.

Comment: There is no such menu, I am collecting different settings, we don't care about which ones, except for the USB mass storage status. I use a Pixel 4 with Android 10. "Enabled" would mean the terminal is connected to a PC via USB and data transfer is enabled.